# Overlapping image caught behind next image

Tags: css, html

I'm sure this is a pretty simple one but can't find the specific answer I'm looking for elsewhere.

Basically, I have a series of side by side images set out in a responsive grid layout. As you hover over each image it zooms and scales the image bigger so it looks like it's coming out towards you.

However, the issues I have is that the later image always overlaps the prior image. I have tried setting all the divs containing the image to the same z-index but to no avail.

I have setup a js.fiddle which demonstrates the issue. I'm hoping to solve with purely CSS.

`JSfiddle link` http://jsfiddle.net/Aloha_Design_Co/46poxw9j/

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
Heath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, give more `z-index` in `.photo-content:hover`.

```
.photo-content:hover {
    background-size: 120%;
    /* in conjuction with the transition below it zooms in on the background image - doesn't change box size in itself; */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /* expands the box to look like it is 3D coming out of page */
    /*  Add z-index */
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46poxw9j/1/)

Comment: Thanks Alireza. I'm sure I tried that but nonetheless it was an easy fix as I suspected. Much appreciated!